# PhpStorm - Supress a 'Method not found in class' for BLOB

Tags: phpstorm

I have a number of files in PhpStorm that have one warning in them and I went that green tick! They are all from using BLOB which of course makes sense as load() is not a function set out in my project. Its a base php function from OCI-Lob.

Line of code is:

```
$zip->addFromString($result['FILE_NAME'], $result['FILE_BLOB']->load());
```

I have tried adding `@var` and `@method comments` (maybe not correctly) in various combinations such as:

```
/** @var $result['FILE_BLOB'] load */
```

I do not want to turn off this check project wide of course as its very useful everywhere else. I just want to suppress it for just this line or even better point it in the right direction somehow. It is annoying to have lots of yellow blocks instead of ticks. Maybe I am just fussy about this as the program is obviously unaffected. Does anyone know of any solution or workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could reference the blob in a separate variable and then put a hint on that variable:

```
/** @var OCI_Lob $fileBlob */
$fileBlob = $result['FILE_BLOB'];
$zip->addFromString($result['FILE_NAME'], $fileBlob->load());
```

Since $result['FILE_BLOB'] is an object it will be assigned by reference, so this should not cause a significant increase of your script's memory usage.

An other option would be to hint the whole results array as an array of OCI_Lob objects. Not pretty, but it will probably solve your code inspection issues as well:

```
/** @var OCI_Lob[] $result */
$zip->addFromString($result['FILE_NAME'], $result['FILE_BLOB']->load());
```

As far as I know it's not possible (yet) to hint specific array keys in PHPDoc comments, so this is the best I can come up with at the moment.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. I tried both of those but it just says 'undefined class OCI_Lob' and then obviously still says method not found in class. Maybe need a direct link to OCI-Lobs location? Also I tried OCI-Lob as Php manual says its that rather than with an underscore. Referencing as a variable I think will work for another one of my warnings though. So thanks. :)

Comment: If you're working in a namespace you might need to use \OCI_Lob (with the backslash in front to reference the root namespace). PHPStorm should be able to recognise the class by default (at least it does for me).

Comment: Boom that worked a treat for both variations! I prefer the second as its one line only and is only a comment so is not touching the code at all. Thanks!